# How can i configure my custom authentication service (developed using Windows Identity Framework) on Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, wif, azure-ad-b2c, acs

I have written a custom authentication service using Windows Identity Framework. Currently, I have registered it as Identity Provider on Windows Azure ACS and have configured a couple of relying parties using this identity provider. With Microsoft closing down the ACS, I need to see if ACS can be replaced by Azure AD or Azure AD B2C? I didn't find any straightforward way of doing this. Can anyone provide me with any documentation or share your thoughts on how best I can handle this migration

Answer (score 1):

Azure ACS can be migrated to Azure AD as well as Azure AD B2C. Refer: [Migrate from Azure ACS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-acs-migration). Consider both the migration plans and follow the best suitable solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ajay. This is the same document I am using but nowhere it allows me to configure my custom STS.